# How to create this type of view TimeSchedule View (Horizontal TimeLine)

Tags: java, android, android-layout, tableview, timeline

How to make this type of view

[image]
[image]

I am trying with Table view and dynamic data , Want header and column also fix Online vertical scroll all except header, Horizontal scroll with header expect First column

I am able to create view with fix header and column but problem with span the column like this with dynamic data

Comment: What have you tried so far? The example XML you provided is simply some nested LinearLayouts within a ScrollView. Have you done some research on layouts like complex TableViews or TimeTableViews?

Comment: is it Horizontal scrollable?

Comment: @Zun will try this

Comment: Use `TableView` with ColSpan or rawspan

Comment: Have you check this **[Android-Week-View](https://github.com/alamkanak/Android-Week-View)**

Comment: What do you mean? Do you want to select a period of time e.g select hours or days with touching?